# Is there a general understanding of what the set $\{e^n : n\geq 1\}$ is made up of?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question in Carother's Real Analysis (Chapter 5 on continuity) text book that I've been working on for quite some time. I haven't gotten anywhere and I'm wondering if I have been misinterpreting it.

> Show that $ \mathbb{N}$ is homeomorphic to the set $\{e^{(n)} : n\geq 1\}$ when considered as a subset of one of the spaces $c_0, \ell _1,\ell _2, \ell_3$. If we instead take the discrete metric on $\mathbb{N}$ show that the map $n\rightarrow e^{(n)}$ is an isometry into $c_0$.

I thought that it was the set of identities in each of the $\ell _p$ spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that each $l_p$ (and $c_0$) is a set of sequences. Then notation "$e^{(n)}$" denotes the sequence which has a $1$ in the $n$th place, and $0$s elsewhere - e.g. $e^{(3)}=(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, . . .)$.

Comment: Oh I see, but how is that a subset of $c_0$? I feel like I've seen that proof or even written it but I can't remember how it goes. what every element of $e^{n}$ is in $c_0$ never mind.

Comment: @JosiahBlaisdell $c_0$ is by definition the space of all sequences converging to $0$. Do you see why each $e^{(n)}$ converges to $0$?

Comment: Yes definitely, heh. Ok ok, so how is it that I can't just say there are countably many such vectors and be done with the problem? Is it actually a really easy problem?

Comment: @JosiahBlaisdell Not every countable set is **homeomorphic** to $\mathbb{N}$ (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual topology is *very* different from $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual topology!).

Comment: Ah yeah ok I see, there are several different statements equivalent to saying a function is homeomorphic. So it sounds like the essence of this problem is showing there is function from $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{e^{(n)} : n \geq 1\} $ where if E is a closed set in $\mathbb{N}$ then $f(E)$ is closed in $\{e^{(n)} : n \geq 1\}$