# If a function produces closed sets in $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$ does it produce closed sets in subspaces of $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I posted a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1967574/is-there-a-general-understanding-of-what-the-set-en-n-geq-1-is-made-up) earlier about the same problem in Chapter 5 of N. L. Carothers Real Analysis.

> Show that $ \mathbb{N}$ is homeomorphic to the set $\{e^{(n)} : n\geq 1\}$ when considered as a subset of one of the spaces $c_0, \ell _1,\ell _2, \ell_3$. If we instead take the discrete metric on $\mathbb{N}$ show that the map $n\rightarrow e^{(n)}$ is an isometry into $c_0$.

I have tried to prove this. First I showed that $\{e^{(n)} : n\geq 1\}$ was a subset of $c_0, \ell _1,\ell _2, \ell_3$ then I claimed that a homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{e^{(n)} : n\geq 1\}$ existed since every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is closed and $f(n) = e^{(n)}$ produces closed sets in $\mathbb{R}^n.$ But each of $c_0, \ell _1,\ell _2, \ell_3$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and so $f$ produces closed sets in each of these subspaces.

Is that true though? If a function produces closed sets in $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$ does it produces closed sets in subspaces of $\mathbb{R} ^{n}$?

Thanks! (ps previous post was deleted)

Comment: Do you mean to write something else instead of $\mathbb R^n$? The elements of $\ell_1$ etc are infinite sequences, and don't belong to $\mathbb R^n$ for any finite $n$.

Comment: Oh no I think that's where my confusion was. So what do I mean though? I am trying to figure out if each of the $\ell _p$ spaces above are somehow structurally similar to some super space and if I am homeomorphic to that super space am I homeomorphic to its subspaces?

Comment: The space of all infinite sequences over $\mathbb R$ (or equivalently the space of functions from $\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$) is a vector space containing each $\ell_p$ as a subspace. However I don't think it has a topology which induces the topology you have on each $\ell_p$. So I think you are better off considering each $\ell_p$ separately.